# Forbidding access to Inherited winform controls

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, custom-controls

I am writing a BaseForm to be inherited. The BaseForm has some basic standard controls of my application.

The problem is:
I want allow inherited forms to use and change this controls, but not remove they from the form.

The biggest problem is a TabControl which Tabs must be added by users Inherited Forms.
If I set "Modifiers" properties of TabControl on BaseForm to private, then inherited Forms will not be able to add new Tabs.
If I set "Modifiers" properties of TabControl on BaseForm to protected, the inherit Forms can remove the TabControl from the BaseForm.

There is a away to stop this? Custom Design?

Comment: Can't you create a template form in visual studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gustavo,

You're standing at the bottom of the first foothill of a mountain range of problems that you'll experience by forcing developers to inherit from a "base form class."  From my experience, frameworks built in this way tend to be very fragile, and difficult for developers to use.

I would imagine that you can overcome this particular obstacle by making the TabControl private and then implementing a public "Tabs" property on the form itself, but I also suspect that you'll get to the peak of this mountain and realize that you have many other even taller mountains in front of you.  I would suggest you rethink the approach altogether.

```
// set the Modifiers property on tabControl1 to "Private" then implement this
public TabControl.TabPageCollection TabPages
{
    get { return tabControl1.TabPages; }
}
```

Inheritance should be used provide common functionality, not to provide a uniform composition.  You really should consider implementing a "core screen" and designing your framework to allow developers to "plug" their controls in to that screen.

The [Composite UI Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480450.aspx) is a good place to start, although there may be something more recent that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.

My project is a plug-in based application. Third-parties uses will add functionally by add-ons. My questions about inherit forms are to control the project inside my company.

Your idea is good, but I don't want try public-properties/private-attributes because I wish use the Visual Design to build the inherited Form.

Comment: It should still work.  If the control is private, it will appear locked in the subclassed forms.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your forms to behave "nicely" within the Visual Studio designer, then you're out of luck - having the Tab Control private will work when you're editing the parent form directly, but will fail when you try to edit descendants.

I believe @Michael Meadows is correct with his answer - having built elaborate frameworks myself in the past that failed to deliver what I wanted.

Broadly speaking, where you're looking at pulling things together with *inheritance*, I believe that *composition* will serve you better. At least, this is my experience.

For lightweight ideas, check out Jeremy Millers series of blog posts [Build your own CAB](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2007/07/25/the-build-your-own-cab-series-table-of-contents.aspx) - lots of good material.